# Single Product page missing product information - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I'm currently working on a custom Wordpress/ Woocommerce template. However the single product page is missing some parts of information (product image, prices, etc.) which is not being displayed. When I activate the storefront theme on the other hand all that information is beeing displayed.

Here's all the details that are not being displayed on my product page:

- List item
- Link for resetting varaition selection
- Price of selected variation
- Stock level
- List item

The following two pictures will show the difference:

[image: Single Product Storefront]

[image: Single Product custom Theme]

This is the code for the single-product.php file in my template's directory:

```
<?php
/**
 * The main file for Single pages 
 */
get_header();
?>
    <div id="single-product" class="padded-content">
        <div class="container">
            <?php
                woocommerce_content();
            ?>
        </div>
        
    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question was quite easy: There was an error in the custom javascript which wasn't directly related but blocked all other WooCommerce scripts apparently. Always look into your console first.